# Querying a database from the shell vs route

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've come across a weird problem. I can query a database from Flask shell:

```
Instance: /usr/src/app/instance
>>> from project.api.models import Flake
>>> Flake.query.all()
[<Flake 1>, <Flake 4>, <Flake 3>]
```

but I get an empty list `[]` when querying the database from route within Flask:

```
@flakes_blueprint.route('/flakes/report', methods=['GET'])
def generate_flakes():
    all_flakes = Flake.query.all()
    print('ALL FLAKES: ', all_flakes)
```

What might be an issue ?

Comment: Can you check whether the binds of the two cases are the same? `from extensions import db; print(db.engine)` should return the same URL in both cases

Comment: @RubenHelsloot  I've just spent couple of hours on converting the `extensions` into Python3-compatible as the module hasn't been ported to Python 3 yet. After fixing all the imports it still throws `ImportError: cannot import name 'db' from 'extensions'`  is there any other way to debug my issue ?

Comment: I'd check that the same code is executed in both cases, just use some print statements in `application.py` to check the `app.config` where you run `db.init_app(app)`

Comment: OK, good idea ....